# Integration tests getting skipped using cobertura

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

I could see my Integration test cases are getting skipped when I execute below command.Could you tell me how to get code coverage report using Cobertura (ver 2.7) for UT and IT cases in Jenkins (ver. 1.631) for a Multi Module Maven (ver. 3.3.9) project in Sonar-Qube (5.1.1).

```
-DargLine="-DDB_SERVER=localhost -DDB_PORT=1234 -DDB_NAME=sample -DDB_USER=sample -DDB_PASSWORD=test -DDB_MAX_POOL=10" -Dcom.test.redis=false clean compiler:compile

-DargLine="-DDB_SERVER=localhost -DDB_PORT=1234 -DDB_NAME=sample -DDB_USER=sample -DDB_PASSWORD=sample -DDB_MAX_POOL=10" -Dcom.test.redis=false cobertura:cobertura
```

Jenkins ver. 1.631 Sonar ver. 5.1.1 Jacoco ver. 0.7.9 Java ver. 1.8 Maven ver. 3.3.9

My Pom file-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>example</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <org.springframework.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <commons.lang.version>2.5</commons.lang.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.15</log4j.version>
        <org.jboss.hibernate.version>5.2.5.Final</org.jboss.hibernate.version>
        <jaxb.version>2.1</jaxb.version>
        <guava.version>19.0</guava.version>
        <jersey.version>2.24.1</jersey.version>
        <jackson.version>2.8.5</jackson.version>
        <jackson.databind.version>2.8.1</jackson.databind.version>
        <cxf.version>3.1.4</cxf.version>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.47</tomcat.version>
        <tomcat.port>18080</tomcat.port>
        <tomcat.client.port>28080</tomcat.client.port>
        <server.version>1.0.0</server.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS z</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <olingo.version>2.0.6</olingo.version>
        <felix.version>5.4.0</felix.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.2</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
            <version>5.1.13</version> <type>jar</type> <scope>compile</scope> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
            <!-- 9.2-1002-jdbc4 -->
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.28</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${org.jboss.hibernate.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.databind.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
        <version>${felix.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <module>test-services</module>
        <module>connector</module>
        <module>test-connector</module>
        <module>serviceproviders</module>
        <module>om</module>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>admin</module>
        <module>client-api</module>
    </modules>


    <profiles>

        <!-- Default profile excludes connectors netsuite and salesforce in admin 
            and client and skips all serviceprovider tests. -->
        <profile>
            <id>no-connector</id>

            <modules>
                <module>connector</module>
                <module>serviceproviders</module>
                <module>om</module>
                <module>common</module>
                <module>admin</module>
                <module>client-api</module>
            </modules>

            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <excludedGroups>salesforce, netsuite, netsuitesso, GoogleDirectoryProvider,hybris4,hybris,hybris5, ftp</excludedGroups>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>

                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <excludedGroups>salesforce, netsuite, netsuitesso, netsuite_min, GoogleDirectoryProvider, hybris4, hybris, hybris5, ftp</excludedGroups>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>

                        <plugin>
                             <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                             <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                             <version>2.7</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report-only</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.7</version>
             </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

failed test error logs-

```
Results :

Failed tests: 
  AccountServiceIT>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run:175->testGetAdminToken:30->BaseITCase.getAdminToken:44 http://localhost:18080/admin/api/token failed with  expected [404] but found [200]
  AdminNotificationIT>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run:175->testGetToken:30->BaseITCase.getAdminToken:44 http://localhost:18080/admin/api/token failed with  expected [404] but found [200]
```

Sonar properties-

```
sonar.projectKey=Test
sonar.projectName=test
sonar.projectVersion=$PipelineId
sonar.modules=module1,module2,module3,cmodule3mon,module6
sonar.cobertura.reportPath=target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
sonar.sources=.
sonar.scm.disabled=true
```

Comment: FYI, the SonarQube properties and logs are irrelevant. You need to figure out how to get the tests to run _before_ analysis.

Comment: Apples and oranges. The exception has nothing to do with running your tests, and appears to be caused by your JGit installation.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Any suggestions on the same/

Comment: That's a separate question

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam issue resolved by adding sonar.scm.disabled=true.

Comment: As an option you can consider using Jacoco there is a default ant support for that